# установить android virtual device

Tags: android, android-studio

Помогите установить android virtual device. Не вижу его в пунктах меню. Гугл не помогает. Правильно я понимаю, чтобы встать на точку останову нужно запустить Run и обязательно иметь какой-либо Virtual Device?
Версия Android Studio - 3.0.1

Comment: Что бы "встать на точку останова" нужно запустить `Debug` и не обязательно иметь виртуальное устройство, можно и реальное.

Answer (score 1):

1. Перейдите `Tools > Android > AVD Manager`.
2. Выберите `Create Virtual Device`
3. Выберите профиль устройства и нажмите `Next`
4. Выберите системный образ (`sistem image`) и нажмите `Next`
5. Настройте (по необходимости) свойства `AVD` и нажмите `Finish`

[Источник](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html)

Answer (score 0):

В том то и дело, что нет в Tools пункта Android и AVD Manager.

Иконка AVD серая, его как такового нет. Но в SDK manager указано, что Android Emulator установлен! Это то, что нужно?

Как установить AVD manager?

Comment: Дополняйте вопрос через [правку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/788727/edit). В ответе должно быть решение вопроса.